# Haskell: list of strings to list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I have list of strings like:

```
["1,AA,3","4,BB,6","7,CC,9"]
```

and I would like to get list of tuples like:

```
[(1,AA,3),(4,BB,6),(7,CC,9)]
```

Please help. Thanks

Edit:

I tried something like:

```
tuples (x:xs) = do
  foo ++ splitOn "," x
  tuples xs
  return foo
```

which would maybe give me list like:

```
"1,AA,3,4,BB,6,7,CC,9"
```

but I dont know how to trasnform it to tuples.

AA,BB,CC should be strings.

Also I would like to if in the list will be something like:

```
["1,AA,3","4,,6","7,CC,9"]
```

transform to

```
[(1,"AA",3),(4,6),(7,"CC",9)]
```

Comment: Also, what should be the type of the value `AA`, `BB` and `CC` ?

Comment: first focus on converting one string to a tuple `f "1, AA, 3" = (1, AA, 3)`, then the larger problem will immediately follow using map.

Comment: `(1,"AA",3)` and `(4,6)` are different types, can't combine in a homogeneous list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import Data.List.Split -- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split

arrayToThreeTuple :: [String] -> [(Int,String,Int)]
arrayToThreeTuple = map (toThreeTuple.splitOn ",")
    where
      toThreeTuple :: [String] -> (Int, String, Int)
      toThreeTuple [a, b, c] = (read a :: Int, b, read c)
      toThreeTuple _ = undefined
```

A bit of explanation: `splitOn` splits a `String` on a given substring, e.g.

```
GHCI List.Split> splitOn "," "1,AA,3"
["1","AA","3"]
```

Next `read` transforms a `String` into a different type, which can either be written `read "1" :: Int` or ghc can infer it by the type signature for you (see `read c`).

The next line is a "catch all line" that caches all other patterns than `[a,b,c]`, indicated by `_` and results in a runtime error (`undefined`).